# Why are printed holes skewed diagonally?

Tags: print-quality, fdm, octoprint, skr-mini-e3

My printer started off as an Anet A6. I've switched it to an aluminum extrusion frame, installed a BLTouch, switched everything to 24 V, gave it an ARM controller, etc. Printing runs over Octoprint. Material is ASA at 255 °C with the bed at 95 °C.

After my most recent modification (switching to IGUS plastic bearings and the aforementioned aluminum frame) I'm experiencing a printing error. The vertical holes are skewed diagonally (picture provided). This seems to be almost not visible at 40 mm/s, substantial at 60 mm/s, and crazy at 80 mm/s (I don't print at this speed but just for testing).

[image: Drawing showing two circles misaligned in both the X and Y directions]

Since it is diagonal, I can't think of a source of the problem. The larger geometries don't seem to be affected. Mostly 3 mm screw holes turn out bad.

Any suggestions on where to look for the source of the problem?

Comment: Tension of the belts is fine? (Not too loose). Also note that the IGUS bearings have a reasonable amount of play, more than the metal bearings. Please add a photo of the upgraded ANET A6 frame.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I started with an Anet A8, installed a BL Touch, installed IGUS bearings, and then moved everything over to a metal frame. Even before changing to a metal frame, I was getting circles skewed at a 45 degree angle. I was hoping the metal frame would fix the issue, but it hasn't.

Comment: I thought it was just misaligned y axis rods, so I tried skewing them in the opposite direction. Now my circles look circular, but squares are now printing skewed. Something seems off, and I'm not sure what. If you figure out the cause, it might fix mine too.

Comment: Could this be caused by powerful cooling essentially blowing the filament to one side? The amount of shift would depend on the viscosity of the filament (i.e. hotter would move more, as you found) and how much contact it has with the layer below...